# Floating Label is not working in Chrome as like mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css

**Floating Label**

The label for the input box will be displayed as a placeholder. Once the user clicks input box to enter some input, the placeholder of input box need to move top as a label.

Gif Image for floating label:
https://media.giphy.com/media/l4Fsjj2HDqjOiTU0U/giphy.gif

I am trying to work with floating label in input box using the pure CSS method. I am using the below code for floating the label in web page.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<style>
.float-label {
   position:relative;
   margin-bottom:-20px;
}
label.set-float {
   color:#999;
   font-size:16px;
   line-height: 18px;
   font-weight:normal;
   position:relative;
   pointer-events:none;
   top:-20px;
   -o-transition:0.6s ease all;
   transition:0.6s ease all;
   -moz-transition:0.6s ease all;
   -webkit-transition:0.6s ease all;
}

.float-input:focus ~ label.set-float, .float-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label.set-float{
   top:-40px;
   font-size:16px;
   line-height:18px;
   color: #787878;
   font-weight: normal;
   padding-left: 0px;
   outline: none;
}

.float-input:focus ~ label.required:after, .float-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label.required:after{
   content: " *";
   color: red;
}

input[type="text"].input {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
   border-radius: 0px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 18px;
   color: #787878;
   width: 320px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

input[type="text"].input:focus {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 0px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 18px;
   color: #333333;
   width: 320px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #97144D;
           box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #97144D;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   outline: none;
}
.form-width {
   width: 352px;
   padding: 32px 15px 30px;
}

.div-pad {
   padding-top: 30px;
}
</style>
<div class="form-width">
    <div class="div-pad">
        <div class="float-label">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="float-input input" name="name" placeholder=""
               autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
            <label class="set-float required">Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

The mentioned code is working to my expectation in the browser Mozilla Firefox but not in Chromium browser.

**Mozilla Firefox**

*Normal View*

[image]

*Focus View*

[image]

**Chrome**

*Normal View*

[image]

*Focus View*

[image]

Can you please help with the suggestion to float the label in all types of desktop/mobile browsers (Safari, Opera and other default browsers) as like Mozilla Firefox.

Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestion and advice.

Comment: I don't really understand what's the actual problem ? ' floating label ' is not a known 'thing' in frontend development. So can you please be more clear about what does `Floating Label is not working in Chrome` mean ? All i can see is a difference in bottom margin ( space ) but that;s about it

Comment: @MihaiT _"'floating label ' is not a known 'thing' in frontend development"_ - oh but yes, sadly it is. https://medium.com/simple-human/floating-labels-are-a-bad-idea-82edb64220f6

Comment: @CBroe sorry. My bad. Didn;t know that was a thing :) I mean, i didn't know that those labels are called 'floating labels' . Well, you learn something everyday. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the `:placeholder-shown` selector. It works the same on firefox and chrome, but firefox seems to have a default (empty) placeholder, while chrome has not. If you specify `" "` one for chrome as well it should work:

```
<input
    id="name"
    type="text"
    placeholder=" "
    class="float-input input"
    name="name"
    autocomplete="off"
    maxlength="50"
    data-dashlane-rid="6b78a2834d4b7713"
    data-form-type="other"
>
```

The problem you are experiencing is, that the `:placeholder-shown` selector only works in chrome when there is a placeholder to be shown. This means, the placeholder has to evaluate to something truthy, e.g. `" "`.

```css
.float-label {
   position:relative;
   margin-bottom:-20px;
}
label.set-float {
   color:#999;
   font-size:16px;
   line-height: 18px;
   font-weight:normal;
   position:relative;
   pointer-events:none;
   top:-20px;
   transition:0.6s ease all;
}

.float-input:focus ~ label.set-float, .float-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label.set-float{
   top:-40px;
   color: #787878;
   padding-left: 0px;
   outline: none;
}

.float-input:focus ~ label.required:after, .float-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label.required:after{
   content: " *";
   color: red;
}

input[type="text"].input {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
   border-radius: 0px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 18px;
   color: #787878;
   width: 320px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

input[type="text"].input:focus {
   border-color: black;
   color: #333333;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #97144D;
   outline: none;
}
.form-width {
   width: 352px;
   padding: 32px 15px 30px;
}

.div-pad {
   padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-width">
    <div class="div-pad">
        <div class="float-label">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="float-input input" name="name" placeholder=" "
               autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
            <label class="set-float required">Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am already using placeholder="", but still the floating of label is not happening.

Comment: Yup, sorry pasted the wrong code. The placeholder appparently has to evaluate to something truthy to be active (Anything other than nothing or `""`)